# How to rotate something inside an a tag with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transform

I cannot make a rotation work inside an `<a href=""></a>` tag.

I have this for example:

```css
.rt {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
}

.rt:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-link ml-auto">SING UP <span class="rt">/</span> ENTER</a>
```

But nothing happens to the forwards slash. I can add .rt to the a tag but I only want the forwards slash to rotate.

Comment: Did you try to change the span to a div?

Comment: Tried that, but then only works when you hover over the forward slash

Comment: try `a.ml-auto:hover .rt{ rotate css}` and that should help that

Comment: It does work by adding `display: inline-block;` but then only when hovering over the forward slash

Comment: @EdgarAlexPoe yep! that did the trick with adding `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Sweet. Glad you got it worked out